# Need to select last week from nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, nvarchar

I have found some fixes about this easily. But I can not change the date column datatype from `nvarchar` to `date` in SQL Server. It is a deal for me to select between last 7 days.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Why can't you convert it? That would make things a lot easier. However there is a function for converting a string to a date in SQL...have you searched for anything already?

Comment: P.s. you've mentioned nvarchar...but this column type only exists in SQL Server as far as I know. Yet the question is tagged MySQL. Which product are you actually using? It matters in this case as the function you need will be different

Comment: Can you tell what kind of error showed to you after your attempt to converting the column type?

Comment: Sorry guys... I have edited my question. It is Sql server. Yes. I tried not to convert but change the column type from server. Now you can answer.

Comment: please clarify the date format?

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You must use convert date from dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in SQL Server.

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,'30-01-2015',103)
```

First you should be convert and update yyyy-mm-dd your row. After that you can easily get last 7 days.